# simple lookup in R by ID and Time

Tags: r, data.table, lookup

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
DT<-data.table(id=c(rep(c("a","b","c","d"),5)),
           year=rep(seq(from = 2010.5,to=2012.5,by = .5),each=4),
           value=rnorm(20,10,1))
DT
     id   year     value
 1:  a 2010.5  8.792934
 2:  b 2010.5 10.277429
 3:  c 2010.5 11.084441
 4:  d 2010.5  7.654302
 5:  a 2011.0 10.429125
 6:  b 2011.0 10.506056
 7:  c 2011.0  9.425260
 8:  d 2011.0  9.453368
 9:  a 2011.5  9.435548
10:  b 2011.5  9.109962
11:  c 2011.5  9.522807
12:  d 2011.5  9.001614
13:  a 2012.0  9.223746
14:  b 2012.0 10.064459
15:  c 2012.0 10.959494
16:  d 2012.0  9.889715
17:  a 2012.5  9.488990
18:  b 2012.5  9.088805
19:  c 2012.5  9.162828
20:  d 2012.5 12.415835
```

I want to add 3 columns which are quite alike, `value_previous_6m`, `value_previous_y` and `value_next_y` for each ID. Row 10 should then look like this:

```
id   year    value value_previous_6m value_previous_y value_next_y
b  2011.5  9.109962    10.50606         10.27743        9.088805
```

I would like to do avoid a plyr function because the total dataset is quite large.

Many thanks in advance,
Tim

Edit: I know that it can be done with the merge function:

```
set.seed(1234)
DT<-data.table(id=c(rep(c("a","b","c","d"),5)),
           year=rep(seq(from = 2010.5,to=2012.5,by = .5),each=4),
           value=rnorm(20,10,1))
DT6mp <- copy(DT)
DT12mp <- copy(DT)
DT6mp[,year:=year-.5]
setkey(DT6mp,id,year);setkey(DT,id,year);setnames(DT6mp,"value","value6mp")
DT <- merge(DT,DT6mp,all.x=T,all.y=F,allow.cartesian=T)
DT12mp[,year:=year-1]
setkey(DT12mp,id,year);setkey(DT,id,year);setnames(DT12mp,"value","value12mp")
DT <- merge(DT,DT12mp,all.x=T,all.y=F,allow.cartesian=T)
DT
```

But I think there should be a nicer method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach ( I voluntary did not aggregated the 3 columns addition to make it clearer):

```
DT[,c('value_previous_6m'):=.SD[match(year-0.5, .SD$year),value], id][
   ,c('value_previous_y'):= .SD[match(year-1, .SD$year),value], id][
   ,c('value_next_y'):=.SD[match(year+1, .SD$year),value], id][]

#    id   year     value value_previous_6m value_previous_y value_next_y
# 1:  a 2010.5  8.792934                NA               NA     9.435548
# 2:  b 2010.5 10.277429                NA               NA     9.109962
# 3:  c 2010.5 11.084441                NA               NA     9.522807
# 4:  d 2010.5  7.654302                NA               NA     9.001614
# 5:  a 2011.0 10.429125          8.792934               NA     9.223746
# 6:  b 2011.0 10.506056         10.277429               NA    10.064459
# 7:  c 2011.0  9.425260         11.084441               NA    10.959494
# 8:  d 2011.0  9.453368          7.654302               NA     9.889715
# 9:  a 2011.5  9.435548         10.429125         8.792934     9.488990
#10:  b 2011.5  9.109962         10.506056        10.277429     9.088805
#11:  c 2011.5  9.522807          9.425260        11.084441     9.162828
#12:  d 2011.5  9.001614          9.453368         7.654302    12.415835
#13:  a 2012.0  9.223746          9.435548        10.429125           NA
#14:  b 2012.0 10.064459          9.109962        10.506056           NA
#15:  c 2012.0 10.959494          9.522807         9.425260           NA
#16:  d 2012.0  9.889715          9.001614         9.453368           NA
#17:  a 2012.5  9.488990          9.223746         9.435548           NA
#18:  b 2012.5  9.088805         10.064459         9.109962           NA
#19:  c 2012.5  9.162828         10.959494         9.522807           NA
#20:  d 2012.5 12.415835          9.889715         9.001614           NA
```

Comment: Thanks, like it that it can be done without plyr or something else and just inside the data table. +1

Comment: More concisely (and maybe faster?) `DT[,(newcols):=lapply(c(.5,1,-1),function(off)value[match(year-off,year)]),by=id]` where `newcols = c("p6mo","py","ny")` or whatever names. (I guess this is what you mean by "voluntarily did not aggregate", though.) Using `.SD` instead of `value` directly, seems a little wasteful, in any case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `shift` from the devel version of `data.table` which has both `lag` and `lead` options

```
library(data.table)#v >= 1.9.5
#library(devtools)
#install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
DT[,c(paste0('val_previous_', c('6m', 'y')), "val_next_y"):=c(shift(value, 1:2), shift(value, 2, type="lead")), by=id]
 #   id   year     value val_previous_6m val_previous_y val_next_y
 #1:  a 2010.5  8.792934              NA             NA   9.435548
 #2:  b 2010.5 10.277429              NA             NA   9.109962
 #3:  c 2010.5 11.084441              NA             NA   9.522807
 #4:  d 2010.5  7.654302              NA             NA   9.001614
 #5:  a 2011.0 10.429125        8.792934             NA   9.223746
 #6:  b 2011.0 10.506056       10.277429             NA  10.064459
 #7:  c 2011.0  9.425260       11.084441             NA  10.959494
 #8:  d 2011.0  9.453368        7.654302             NA   9.889715
 #9:  a 2011.5  9.435548       10.429125       8.792934   9.488990
 #10:  b 2011.5  9.109962       10.506056      10.277429   9.088805
 #11:  c 2011.5  9.522807        9.425260      11.084441   9.162828
 #12:  d 2011.5  9.001614        9.453368       7.654302  12.415835
 #13:  a 2012.0  9.223746        9.435548      10.429125         NA
 #14:  b 2012.0 10.064459        9.109962      10.506056         NA
 #15:  c 2012.0 10.959494        9.522807       9.425260         NA
 #16:  d 2012.0  9.889715        9.001614       9.453368         NA
 #17:  a 2012.5  9.488990        9.223746       9.435548         NA
 #18:  b 2012.5  9.088805       10.064459       9.109962         NA
 #19:  c 2012.5  9.162828       10.959494       9.522807         NA
 #20:  d 2012.5 12.415835        9.889715       9.001614         NA
```

---

Deliberately long version to avoid mistakes.

```
DT[, value_previous_6m := shift(value, 1), by=id
   ][, value_previous_y:= shift(value, 2), by=id
   ][, value_next_y:= shift(value, 2, type="lead"), by=id]
```

Comment: I'm probably using the wrong shift function since it does not work... Could you tell me from which package this shift is?

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht The function `shift` is available for `data.table v1.9.5`. You can install it from Github `library(devtools); install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm probably still doing something wrong.. I get the error msg:                `Error in shift(value, 1:2) : object 'Cshift' not found`

Comment: can you add your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: `R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45 tools_3.1.3 `

Comment: shift(1:10) also doesn't work: `shift(1:10)
Error in shift(1:10) : object 'Cshift' not found`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Problem you face is beyond my expertise. Maybe, @Arun can help.

Comment: I remember having some problems with `shift` when I first moved to `1.9.5`, but they went away without me doing anything in particular. Perhaps try restarting your `R` session and installing from a blank slate? Inspired by [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1011)

Comment: I found that I was working with R3.1.3, I now updated to R3.2 and will test it later. I already restarted my `R` session and that didn't help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

here's a `dplyr`+`tidyr` solution, which is faster.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data_frame(id=c(rep(c("a","b","c","d"),5)),
                 year=rep(seq(from = 2010.5,to=2012.5,by = .5),each=4),
                 value=rnorm(20,10,1))
df %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value_previous_6m = lag(value),
         value_previous_y = lag(value, 2),
         value_next_y = lead(value, 2)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(year)
```

runtime: 0.016 seconds

with Colonel Beauvel's `data.table` solution it took 0.023 seconds on the same machine.

EDIT: Khashaa's `data.table` solution is faster than he `dplyr` solution i provided. it took 0.007 seconds.

Comment: certainly because I am updating column per column. But the aggregated version may be faster than `dplyr`.